# How to use MathJax in Ionic 2 Application

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, mathjax

I downloaded MathJax from [Github MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax). Used [MathJax-grunt-cleaner](http://MathJax-grunt-cleaner) to reduce the size of the package. I then included the MathJax folder in my `www` folder. Inserted `<script type="text/javascript" src="mathjax/MathJax.js"></script>` in the head section of the index.html. Still, MathJax is not running on `pages`. Please let me know if there is any way to include 3rd Party js files in Ionic 2 Project.

Answer (score 0):

MathJax rendering in Ionic 2 Application needs a Directive. Refer this [Nice illustration by @PrithiviRajG](https://github.com/PrithiviRajG/IONIC2MathJaxImpl)